# Oracle SQL insert if not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert, insert-select

I have table `foo` with PK `int id`,`varchar state`

```
table foo:
- int id
- varchar state
- int code1
- int code2
```

I want to do an sql insert if the record not already exist.

To complete the insert statement, I have to retrieve some info with an insert select.

In input I have:

```
id = 1, state = 'A'
```

In the insert I have to fill the other field with values retrieved with insert select.

```
code1 and code2 where id = 1 (they are always the same for id = x)
```

Normally I have to do:

1- a select with `where id=1 and state=1`, and if not exist I will have to do the sql insert

2- if record not exist retrieve the values of fields `code1 and code2 when id=1`

3- do the insert

Is it possible to do all in one query?

```
select * from foo where id=1 and state = 'A'
```

if not exist already:

```
select code1,code2 from foo where id=1; #1,2
insert into foo(id, state, code1, code2) values (1,'A', 1, 2);
```

is it possible to merge in one query?

Thanks

Comment: Adjusted the answer based on your moving target question;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into foo (id, some)
    select 1, 'text'
    from dual
    where not exists (select 1 from foo where id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the *magical Oracle hint [`IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG) for this purpose. The hint silently skips the duplicated inserted row - normally causing `ORA-00001: unique constraint (...) violated.

I assume following table setup:

```
create table foo
(id number not null,
 status varchar2(1) not NULL,
 code1 varchar2(10),
 code2 varchar2(10));

alter table foo add (primary key (id, status)); 

insert into foo (id,status, code1,code2) values(1,'a','xxx', 'xxx');
insert into foo (id,status, code1,code2) values(1,'b','xxx', 'xxx');

insert into foo (id,status, code1,code2) values(2,'b','yyy', 'yyy');
commit;
```

So now you want to ignore the insert with key `1` and perform the insert with key `2` using the `code`s from the record with status `'b'`

This should give you the idea how to proceed:

```
insert /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX (foo (id, status)) */ into foo (id,status, code1,code2) 
values( 1, 'a', 
(select code1 from foo where id = 1 and status = 'b'),
(select code2 from foo where id = 1 and status = 'b'));

0 rows created.

insert /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX (foo (id, status)) */ into foo (id,status, code1,code2) 
values( 2, 'a', 
(select code1 from foo where id = 2 and status = 'b'),
(select code2 from foo where id = 2 and status = 'b'));

1 rows created.
```

Adjust the subquery to get the `code1` and `code2` as required - you may use `max(code1)` and ignore the `status`.

Use bind variable to pass the `id` (three times) in the query.

Answer (score 0):

In your table, `id` is a primary key. So oracle will throw an error if you're trying to insert a row with an existing `id`.
You can handle that error however you wish.

But if you "really" want to check before inserting, you can try a PL/SQL block.

### PL/SQL

```
declare
  _id INTEGER
begin
  SELECT id into _id from foo;
exception
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then
    insert into foo(id,some) values (1,'text');
end;
/
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you have the / at the end. This will run your PL/SQL block.

Basically this block tries to select a row with the given `id`. If exists, simply ends the block normally. If no rows are returned, then this is an 'exception' for the block and you 'handle' it by inserting what you need to.

### Another way

```
begin
  insert into foo(id,some) values (1,'text');
exception
  when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Already exists');
end;
/
```

**NOTE:** If you want to see any output of a PL/SQL block, you may need to do
`set serveroutput on;`
before running any PL/SQL block.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in a single statement in Oracle is to [use the MERGE statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606). In your case you'd do something like:

```
MERGE INTO FOO
  USING (SELECT f.ID,
                'A' AS STATE,
                f.CODE1,
                f.CODE2
           FROM FOO f
           WHERE f.ID = 1) d
    ON (d.ID = FOO.ID AND
        d.STATE = FOO.STATE)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (ID, STATE, CODE1, CODE2)
  VALUES
    (d.ID, d.STATE, d.CODE1, d.CODE2)
```

Best of luck.